# Dynamic Linq using SqlMethods.Like

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-expressions

I'm trying to build a dynamic Linq to Sql query and it's going pretty well, except for invoking the SqlMethods.Like method. My code is below and the body of the linq statement being generated looks like this:

```
Body = {((((log.ClientCode == "C1") OrElse 
(log.ClientCode == "C2")) AndAlso 
(log.Source == "S1")) AndAlso Like("Message", "%1%"))}
```

As you can see, it attempts to call "Like" without the SqlMethods class. Any idea what I'm doing wrong??

```
    public IEnumerable<ILog> Get(int pageNumber, int pageCount,
        List<string> clientCodes, List<string> sources, List<LogLevel> logLevels,
        string messageContains, string userNameContains,
        DateTime? dateStart, DateTime? dateEnd)
    {
        var expressions = new List<Expression>();

        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Data.Logging.Log), "log");

        if (clientCodes != null && clientCodes.Count > 0)
        {
            expressions.Add(CreateClientCodeExpression(pe, clientCodes));
        }
        if (sources != null && sources.Count > 0)
        {
            expressions.Add(CreateSourceExpression(pe, sources));
        }

        if (logLevels != null && logLevels.Count > 0)
        {
            expressions.Add(CreateLogLevelExpression(pe, logLevels));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(messageContains))
        {
            expressions.Add(CreateMessageExpression(pe, messageContains));
        }

        Expression exp = null;
        if (expressions.Count > 0)
        {
            exp = expressions[0];
        }
        for (var i = 1; i < expressions.Count; i++)
        {
            exp = Expression.AndAlso(exp, expressions[i]);
        }

        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Data.Logging.Log, bool>>(exp, pe);
        var results = DbContext.Logs.Where(predicate).ToList();

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            yield return ConvertDbLogToLog(result);
        }
    }

    private Expression CreateClientCodeExpression(ParameterExpression pe, List<string> clientCodes)
    {
        Expression result = null;
        clientCodes.ForEach(cc =>
        {
            MemberExpression me = Expression.Property(pe, "ClientCode");
            ConstantExpression ce = Expression.Constant(cc);

            if (result == null) { result = Expression.Equal(me, ce); }
            else { result = Expression.OrElse(result, Expression.Equal(me, ce)); }
        });

        return result;
    }

    private Expression CreateSourceExpression(ParameterExpression pe, List<string> sources)
    {
        Expression result = null;
        sources.ForEach(s =>
        {
            MemberExpression me = Expression.Property(pe, "Source");
            ConstantExpression ce = Expression.Constant(s);

            if (result == null) { result = Expression.Equal(me, ce); }
            else { result = Expression.OrElse(result, Expression.Equal(me, ce)); }
        });

        return result;
    }

    private Expression CreateLogLevelExpression(ParameterExpression pe, List<LogLevel> logLevels)
    {
        Expression result = null;
        logLevels.ForEach(l =>
        {
            MemberExpression me = Expression.Property(pe, "LogLevel");
            ConstantExpression ce = Expression.Constant(l.ToString());

            if (result == null) { result = Expression.Equal(me, ce); }
            else { result = Expression.OrElse(result, Expression.Equal(me, ce)); }
        });

        return result;
    }

    private MethodCallExpression CreateMessageExpression(ParameterExpression pe, string message)
    {
        return Expression.Call(typeof(SqlMethods).GetMethod("Like", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }),
            Expression.Constant("Message"), Expression.Constant(string.Format("%{0}%", message)));
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Message` be a property like in other conditions?

Comment: What's your original statement?

Comment: @IvanStoev When I make that change, I get this exception: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Like(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @GertArnold I don't understand the question. Are you asking what I expect the query to be when I'm done?

Comment: LINQ To Entities? Then why you are speaking (and tagged the question) for LINQ To SQL? They are totally different, and of course LTE does not support `SqlMethods`

Comment: No, the statement that gave rise to the generated body. On the other hand, that's not hard to infer.

Comment: if you are really targeting EF, please update the question (and tag) so we can provide you a solution.

Comment: @IvanStoev You're right. My bad. I guess I'll just use Contains.

Comment: Ok, I see you got the answer! Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the 'Contains' operator is not always sufficient.  For example, if you want to search something like this: 'first%last'.  The '%' in the string will be taken literally instead of a wildcard as intended.  In order to use the 'SqlMethods.Like' operator you can use the following:

```
public static MethodCallExpression Like(this ParameterExpression pe, string value)
{
    var prop = Expression.Property(pe, pe.Name);
    return Expression.Call(typeof(SqlMethods), "Like", null, prop, Expression.Constant(value));
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can skip the `Like` invocation, and use `Contains`, which both Linq-to-SQL and Linq-to-Entities correctly translate to a `LIKE` statement. You even save the quoting! (which, btw, you are doing wrong).

```
private MethodCallExpression CreateMessageExpression(ParameterExpression pe, string message)
{
    return Expression.Call(Expression.Property(pe, "Message"), "Contains", null, Expression.Constant(message));
}
```